# MarkLogic Cluster - Disk Space unevenly distributed

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

My company has hosted MarkLogic on Amazon and we have a cluster with 3 MarkLogic instances. All 3 instances have volume attached of size 2700 GiB.
However when I open Monitoring Dashboard and check Disk Space tab, I see data is unevenly distributed.

**Instance 1
Forest Data - 1442GB
Forest Reserve - 416GB
Free Space - 42GB**

**Instance 2
Forest Data - 1445GB
Forest Reserve - 418GB
Free Space - 567GB**

**Instance 3
Forest Data - 1440GB
Forest Reserve - 414GB
Free Space - 643GB**

My Question is why in Instance 1 I am seeing less free space (42 GB)? Data should be evenly distributed.
How to mitigate this?

Comment: It is the other way around. Forest data is balanced equally, but free space is uneven. Something else on Instance 1 is eating up 500+Gb of free space. Is something else running on Instance 1, next to MarkLogic?

Comment: For future questions, make sure you also use the [marklogic] tag, as more people look at that tag.